# Pointer on struct can not be copied to another pointer inside a function

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, copy

I have a question, that sounds really stupid but i just don't get it. I try to program a small shell using following Struct for a list:

```
struct shellvalue {
    char* word;
    char isorder;
    char isarg;
    char ispipe;
    char isamp;
    unsigned int wordcount;
    unsigned int ordercount;
    struct shellvalue* next;
};
```

I initiate two pointers in the main-method with

```
struct shellvalue* start;
struct shellvalue* current;
```

Then i allocate now memory for the first element with:

```
void addtoken(char* word, int counter, struct shellvalue* start,
    struct shellvalue* current)
{
  if (counter == 0)
  { //creating first element
    size_t structsize = sizeof(struct shellvalue);
    struct shellvalue* tmp = (struct shellvalue*) malloc(structsize);
    tmp->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(tmp->word, word);
    start = tmp;
    start->next = NULL;
    current = start;
  }
  else
  { // append new element
    struct shellvalue* new = (struct shellvalue*) malloc(
        sizeof(struct shellvalue));
    new->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(new->word, word);
    current->next = new;
    current = new;
  }
}
```

But when i try to do

```
start = tmp;
```

I can see in the debugger, that start has still the value NULL from the main-Method. Both pointers seem of the same type to me and i get no warnigs or anything with this compilertags

`-Wall -ansi -Wconversion -pedantic -m64`

I really don't see, what i do wrong.

Comment: C is pass by value. `start` inside the function is only a **copy** of what was passed into the function on calling it.

Comment: 1+ for using a debugger! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment `start = tmp` only changes the value of `start` inside `addtoken()`. Since pointers are passed by value, this doesn't alter the pointer `start` outside of your function. In order to achieve this, you have to pass a *pointer to pointer* into your function:

```
void addtoken(char* word, int counter, struct shellvalue** start, struct shellvalue** current) {
    // ..
    // replace assignments to start/current with:
    *start = tmp
    // ..
}
```

Then, when invoking your function:

```
struct shellvalue* start;
struct shellvalue* current;

addToken(word, counter, &start, &current);
```

**My suggested alternative:**

Use a struct to hold both of your pointers, and pass a pointer to it into your function:

```
struct shellvalue_list {
    struct shellvalue* start;
    struct shellvalue* end;
};

void addtoken(struct shellvalue_list* list, char* word, int counter) {
    // ..
    list->start = tmp;
    // ..
}
```

This is a common idiom for object-oriented code in C.

Comment: Oh how could i be so blind. Thank you very much!